# NGINX deny access to directory and inner files, including js/css

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to deny access to few directories, as well as all sub-directories and files, including JS/CSS files.

I have this configuration, and it works for the most part, but it doesn't deny access to .js file I have.

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     DOMAIN www.DOMAIN;
    root            /home/me/www/app;

    index           index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex       on;

    client_max_body_size    20m;    
    fastcgi_read_timeout    600;
    #Forbid access to these directories
    location ~ /(data|dev|py)/ {
            deny all;
            return 403;
    }
    #Force download on PDF files
    location ~* /(.*\.pdf) {
            types { application/octet-stream .pdf; }
            default_type  application/octet-stream;
    }

    location / {
            index           index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    #API
    location /api/v1/ {
            index           index.php;
            try_files       $uri $uri/ /api/v1/index.php?$args;
    }
    #php support
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

            include         /etc/nginx/conf.d/php_generic;

            fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/me/www/site1;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm-me.sock;
    }

    error_page      404     /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }

    error_log       /home/me/logs/error.log;
    access_log      /home/me/logs/access.log;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
  }
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT / RESOLVED**

Well, the website is behind CloudFlare, so after 30 minutes of pulling my hair off, link is no longer accessible, which tells me that CloudFlare had it cached and served it, even tho nginx config was changed.

Comment: Is there an entry in the access log?

Comment: No, there's no entry in access log.